# Problem to log in in to a new instralled Ubuntu

Tags: login

I have read the answers on the same question, but I couldn't find the answer.
I have installed complete new Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on my Sony Vaio, but I can't log in.
I have try with different passwords - log and shorts - but it always comes back to the log in screen.
To be possible to check some things I had to add my user and pass - after pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 - and it works.
But when I try to log in is writing not my user, but my name - maybe this is the problem. How can I change it?

I have try to check ownership for some files - stays my name on the side.
I have move the cache - the same.

Some other ideas?

The type of the laptop is Sony Vaio VPCEB4J1E

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to compiz not able to use your 3d card driver. Without any details (Vaio model etc.) It is hard to diagnose.

Solution is to install xfce4-desktop and switch session from lightdm.login screen. But it is a dirty temporray hack just to be able to run X.

Comment: Sorry - I have add some more info in the question.

Comment: Now it gets better. In (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2228404) we have a thread that explains what is happening. As I thought Unity (better say Compiz) is not compitable with your card =) I would say it is a pain in the ... you know... and my recommendation is to avoid Compiz at all. Sadly, the only way now is to use Xubuntu, as gnome-backports are now deprecated and pout of support.

Comment: If you really up to go with Ubuntu... well (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450) is a link for you.

Comment: And, if I did not convince you... (http://askubuntu.com/questions/459930/after-installing-fglrx-on-ubuntu-14-04-there-is-no-backlight-hd-5470-is-there)

Comment: Hi Thank you for this info - I will try it. Meanwhile I have install 12 and then update it to 14 and it works

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install proper driver.
[Procedure is described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643635/how-to-install-ati-radeon-hd5470-proprietary-drivers-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Then check my comments as there are issued with Ubuntu compiz and ATI as a GPU in Sony systems.